# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n)!}=\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

The Taylor series for $\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n)!}.$$
How should I go about proving it? I can't find a closed form for $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}$.

Comment: Arent you supposed to know Taylor's expansion of $\sin x$?

Comment: I already know the Taylor series for $\sin x$. But how could it help in this case?

Comment: Just substitution and rewriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $\;\sin u=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n u^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, so substituting $2x$ to $u$, we obtain
$$\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}=\frac1{2x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)\:(2n)!}.
$$

Comment: Easier than lab's approach, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2x)^{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n)!}=\dfrac1{2ix}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}=2i\sin2x$$